# What does the expression (item) do in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

What does the expression (item) do in a list comprehension (the first one)?

```
def anagrams(word, words): 
  return [item for item in words if sorted(item)==sorted(word)]
           ^

print(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']))
```

Comment: It's what gets put in the `list`

Comment: It is the item from the subsequent `for item in words`; so it is each element in the list `words`.

Answer (score 1):

The array `words` is iterated, where `item` refers to the element in that array for a given iteration.

When the varaible `item` is placed at the start of the list comprehension, this variable is placed into the resulting array.

In other words, all items are being copied from `words` and being returned, with one exception, some items are ignored based on the filtering condition `if sorted(item) == sorted(word)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to the code below. Maybe you can understand easier this way.

```py
def anagrams(word, words):
    result=[]
    for item in words:
       if sorted(item) == sorted(word):
           result.append(item)
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

That expression, `item` is just an [atom](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms), it evaluates to whatever the identifier `item` is referring to at that time.

Here, `item` is the target list of the `for` clause in the [list comprehension expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms). Just like in a for-loop statement, the target list is assigned the next value in the iterator on each iteration.